# How can I delete the contents of a directory with systemd service file?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that stores files in a directory.  I need to ensure that the directory is empty each time the service starts.  I thought that adding `ExecStartPre=+/bin/rm path/to/the/directory/*` to the .service file would get the job done but after restarting the service, the files in the directory remain.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish emptying the directory at service startup?

Answer (score 1):

See https://serverfault.com/a/1051433/179897

Systemd doesn't do glob expansion so it tries to delete a single dir named `path/to/the/directory/*`, it acts as if the `*` is the name of the last subdirectory.
You can work around this by using:

```
ExecStartPre=+/bin/bash -c 'rm -rf /path/to/the/directory/*'
```

Answer (score -1):

I used `-` instead of `+` and used the full path (more on [official docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)). I added `-f` to `rm` in case you have both files and folders.

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rm -f /path/to/the/directory/*
```

I tested with the following file (`/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=MyDaemon Simple Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rm /tmp/mydaemon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ls /tmp
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And tested my service file with:

```
# systemctl start mydaemon
# systemctl status mydaemon
# systemctl restart mydaemon
```

Tested your particular scenario with:

```
# touch /tmp/mydaemon
# ls -al /tmp/mydaemon
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 28 12:38 /tmp/mydaemon

# systemctl restart mydaemon
# ls -al /tmp/mydaemon
ls: cannot access /tmp/mydaemon: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The `+` prefix has a [different meaning](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) than `-`.
The `*` in the original command is the problem, systemd does not do glob expansion in ExecStart & friends.